# eval issues in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, eval

While running `eval()` in IE7 if my JSON contains language-specific characters like `è`, it's not evolved properly. Is there a way I can change the language settings to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `JSON.parse()` from [the official JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)?

Comment: If eval doesn't work then is a encoding problem, 
json.parse can't do miracles.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your charset in your html, or probably you're serving the wrong content-type server side:

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html

http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset